# Split string into variables(sqlserver)

Tags: delimiter

Any way to split below string  using & as delimiter and store the result in five variables without using table variable in sqlserver
Input=`11&12&13&14&15`
output
a=11,b=12,c=13,d=14,e=15

Comment: What language are you discussing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to judge from your question what language you are working in and how you have attempted to solve the problem yourself. Please edit your post to include this information.